# Gauge redundancy and Gauge fixing

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

Take any gauge invariant theory, for instance QED. The QED Lagrangian is invariant under
$$A_{\mu}(x)\rightarrow A'_{\mu}(x)=A_{\mu}(x)+\partial_{\mu}. \alpha(x)$$
I have chosen a local gauge transformation, but I think it doesn't matter. Usually we try to make a choice of gauge with which we are going to be working. A particular choice of gauge, for instance, can be
$$A_0'=0.$$
I have some questions about the gauge choice we have just made:

1. Here we have set one out of the four components of the gauge field to be zero. This can be justified as follows: we can always choose $\alpha(x)$ to be s.t.
   $$\partial_{0}\alpha(x)=-A_0(x)\Rightarrow A_0'(x)=0.$$
   Is this a valid way of justifying the gauge choice?
2. How large is my freedom of choosing the components of the gauge field I wish to set to zero? Can I choose a gauge in which all of them are zero? If not, what is the maximum number of components I can set to zero by choosing an appropriate gauge?

Comment: Remember that a gauge transformation leaves the electric and magnetic fields invariant. If you cancel the gauge field $A^\mu$, there is no electric and magnetic field anymore!

Comment: Hi @Christophe and thank you for your comment. This would imply that I can not set $\partial_{\mu}\alpha(x)=-A_{\mu}(x)$, as I understand it, correct? Is there some underlying fundamental principle as to why something like that can not be happenning? Or do we simply say that such a field does not describe the physics we want it to describe and we do not consider it?

Comment: I think that there is simply no solution $\alpha(x)$ to the equation $\partial_\mu\alpha=-A_\mu(x)$ for a general $A_\mu$.